# Changing QGIS attribute table shortcut?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, shortcuts

I am using [QGIS ver 2.14.8], Windows 7

I am doing repeated work to check the point feature's attribute .

Clicking one feature and `Ctrl + j` ( zoom map to the selected rows)

and checking environment from other satellite map layers (to make sure filled information is correct manually)

The points are far away from to each other and the satellite map takes much time to rendering, so I should click or press `Ctrl + j` to saving time after checking a point .

I can change the shortcut in map window, but it's not possible in attribute table window shortcut

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could add some screenshots from your map window, to give us an idea what exactly you are doing, esp. '...take much time to rendering' for raster maps sound like missing pyramids or slt. to me.

Comment: @babo Can you speed up the rendering of satellite image by parallel CPU cores? (If it's not done yet.) Go to  **Menu | Settings | Options** , and select **Rendering** tab. You can check "Render layers in parallel using many CPU cores" and "Max cores to use:". Then try increase numbers of your CPU as many as you have on your machine...hope it works.

Answer (score 4):

I often have to visually audit points numbering in the thousands and I find this plugin to be a lifesaver:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Go2NextFeature3/

It can automatically zoom or pan to the next item in the attribute table and even select it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, whether I got you right or not, but can't you simply right-click somewhere in a row in the attribute table and select 'Zoom to Object' in the small context menu? I know for sure, that moving your hand away from the keys to the mouse is also bothering and time consuming, but perhaps this is a workaround for you...

[image]

Comment: i possibly do that you show me. but still takes some time.... and to click accurately also takes concentration and it makes tired. maybe i should go to the gym and learn some stamina for doing this job haha.. anyway thanks very much

Comment: There is a key to open the context menu (in my case between AltGr and Ctrl), so no need to move your hand away from the keyboard :)